# My.User.CurrentPrincipal not working in Class Library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get the current username in a Windows environment that uses Windows Authentication.  The code exists in a class library that is built and referenced within a separate Visual Studio application:

```
Function GetUserName() As String
    If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is 
      Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then
        ' The application is using Windows authentication.
        ' The name format is DOMAIN\USERNAME.
        Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
        Dim username As String = parts(1)
        Return username
    Else
        ' The application is using custom authentication.
        Return My.User.Name
    End If
End Function
```

I get an error when it's located in the class library.  My.User.CurrentPrincipal comes back with {System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal} and My.User.Name is blank.  When I put the exact same code into a brand new windows forms application it works - My.User.CurrentPrincipal comes back with {System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal} and My.User.Name is the user's login name.

Microsoft documentation suggests that the My.User object will work in class libraries.  Does anyone know why I'm getting different values when it's put into a class library and added as a .dll reference to a parent application?

The parent application is a class library that is an add-in for Microsoft PowerPoint.  The code in the parent application that calls the above code (called UsageDataCollection.dll) is:

```
Public Class rbnOvaPowerPoint
    Private DataCollector As UsageDataCollection.DataCollector
    Private Sub butShare_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles butShare.Click
        OtherTasks.CreateMailItem()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then in a separate module:

```
Module OtherTasks
    Private DataCollector As New UsageDataCollection.DataCollector
    Sub CreateMailItem()
        Dim OutlookApp As Outlook._Application = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = Nothing
        Dim mailRecipients As Outlook.Recipients = Nothing
        Dim mailRecipient As Outlook.Recipient = Nothing
        DataCollector.UsageStatistics("CreateMailItem")
        Try
            mail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            mail.Subject = "OvaPowerPoint"
            mail.Body = "Check out OvaPowerPoint, a custom-built Arup add-in for PowerPoint!" & Strings.Chr(13) & Strings.Chr(13) & "About the Add-In:" & Strings.Chr(13) & "http://wiki.oasys.intranet.arup.com/X-Wiki/index.php/OvaPowerPoint" & Strings.Chr(13) & Strings.Chr(13) & "Installation File:" & Strings.Chr(13) & "\\n-ynas12\Software\Custom%20Applications\Plug-Ins\Microsoft%20PowerPoint\OvaPowerPoint\setup.exe"
            mail.Display(True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
            "An exception is occured in the code of add-in.")
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(mailRecipient) Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipient)
            If Not IsNothing(mailRecipients) Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipients)
            If Not IsNothing(mail) Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

And the UsageStatistics subroutine in UsageDataCollection.dll looks like:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
    Public Class DataCollector
    Public Sub UsageStatistics(myAction As String)
        Dim myAssemblyName As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly.GetName.Name
        Dim myFilePath As String = "\\n-ywpress01\uploads\UsageData\" & myAssemblyName & ".csv"
        Using LogFile As New StreamWriter(myFilePath, True)
            LogFile.WriteLine("[" & DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH':'mm':'ss") & "]" & Chr(44) & GetUserName() & Chr(44) & GetUserLocation() & Chr(44) & myAction)
            LogFile.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks

Zak

Comment: From where is this function called?

Comment: Hi Chris, right now it's called from a Class Library that is an add-in for Microsoft PowerPoint.  I'll edit my post to include some details on that.

Comment: I've been running some tests and discovered that UsageDataCollection.dll works if it is referenced by a Windows Forms Application.  Something happens when I try to reference it in a PowerPoint Add-In (which takes the form of a Class Library)...

Comment: I don't know anything about PowerPoint addins, but my thinking was similar.  I was wonder if you were calling it from a Windows Service, which might have resulted in the same problem.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

In the MS docs, it says

> For Windows applications, only projects built on the Windows Application  template initialize the `My.User` object by default. In all other Windows  project types, you must initialize the `My.User` object by calling the  `My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser` Method explicitly or by assigning a value to `CurrentPrincipal`.

The fix in your code is:

```
Function GetUserName() As String
    My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser() 'pulls the network credentials into .NET
    If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is 
      Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then
        ' The application is using Windows authentication.
        ' The name format is DOMAIN\USERNAME.
        Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
        Dim username As String = parts(1)
        Return username
    Else
        ' The application is using custom authentication.
        Return My.User.Name
    End If
End Function
```